# ldapsearch, follow dn-s

Tags: ldap

I'm somewhat confused about LDAP query syntax.

Suppose there are two inetOrgPerson records for two employees, M being manager of E (that is, there's a 'manager' attribute with manager's dn as a value in E's entry).

I want to look up E's manager's attribute, like phone number, by performing a search that would find E's entry by matching some known attribute of E, then follow the dn found in 'manager' attribute and find M, then display M's phone number – all in a single LDAP query. Is that possible with, say, ldapsearch utility quering an OpenLDAP server?

Answer (score 4):

No.  You are doing two things, looking up object A and its attributes then looking up object B  based on object A's attributes.  No LDAP server I'm aware of offers to do that in one step.  You could write some code that implements such a method, but underneath it'll be two LDAP calls

Comment: "No LDAP server I'm aware of offers to do that in one step" - in OpenLDAP it is used quite extensively implementing the ACL-s. Hence the question...

Comment: @badbishop LDAP ACLs get to do all of the implicit ldap searches they want. The code that processes ACLs *does* have to perform those queries, you just don't see it because you're not going through that plugin's code, and internal queries aren't logged.